# STL O(log(N)) algo to find if an element belongs to any interval in a set of non-overlapping ordered intervals

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11

For example we have `[[0,3],[4, 7], [8, 10]]`
I want, given a query `q` to retrieve the interval (for example `q = 9` returns `[8, 10]`) or a value indicating that the query fell off all the intervals.

I tried implementing it with `std::map<int, int>` and using `lower_bound`, but it's a pain and leads to really ugly code (lots of edge cases using `lower_bound`). Any better design ideas?

Comment: You can binary search among the left sides of the intervals (i.e. {0, 4, 8, ...}) to find the largest one less than `q` (for `q = 9` you get 8).  Then compare it with the right side of that interval (here 10) to see if it is in fact inside that interval.  If not then it cannot be inside any interval.

Comment: Yeah that's what I explained I'm doing, the trick here is to find an STL container allowing to do that in a mildly clean way

Comment: What about using `std::lower_bound` to search the *right* sides, then compare with the corresponding left side?  I don't see any edge cases there.

Comment: @A.Fenzry *in a mildly clean way* -- It is subjective as to what is "mildly clean".  What may be "dirty" to you could be "clean" to another programmer.

Comment: I'm not seeing the "edge cases"?  One call to `std::lower_bound` to find the least right endpoint `b` that is not less than the query `q`.  If it fails, there's no match (`q` is past the last interval).  If it succeeds, compare `q` with the left endpoint `a` of that interval.  Succeed if `q >= a`, fail otherwise.  What are the edge cases where this doesn't work?

Comment: Let's say the cleanest way with the tools available, I suppose that's a better definition. Is really map and lower bound my best shot? Need to check for size > 1, then need to check it is not the first interval (because in this case what lower bound is pointing to is that no interval matches), etc.

Comment: I don't see why it has to be `std::map`, you could use `std::vector<std::pair<int,int>>` just as well if you keep it sorted.  And I think my proposed algorithm works just fine if the size is 1 or even 0.

Comment: std::map to sort them automatically initially at insertion.

Comment: You are right about going from the right. Editing previous comment and if you want to format as an answer I will accept

Comment: If you get all the intervals in advance, you can put them in a `std::vector` and `std::sort` them.  If you may be adding them as you go, then `std::map` would work, but `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>` seems more intuitive to me.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, a `std::set<std::pair<int,int>>` would allow the range items to be sorted automatically.

Then the `std::lower_bound` can be used to find the value on the right of the range.

Here is an example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <set>
using RangeSet = std::set<std::pair<int, int>>;

std::pair<RangeSet::const_iterator, bool> testLookup(const RangeSet& sSet, int value)
{
    auto iter = std::lower_bound(sSet.begin(), sSet.end(), std::make_pair(value, value),
                [](const auto& pr1, const auto& pr2) { return pr1.second < pr2.second; });
    if (iter == sSet.end())
        return { sSet.end(), false };
    if (iter == sSet.begin() && value < iter->first)
        return { sSet.end(), false };
    return { iter, true };
}

int main()
{
    RangeSet rSet = { { 0, 3 }, { 4, 7 }, { 8, 10 } };
    for (int i = -4; i < 20; ++i)
    {
        auto interval = testLookup(rSet, i);
        if (interval.second)
            std::cout << "The value " << i << " is in range (" << interval.first->first << "," << interval.first->second << ")\n";
        else
            std::cout << "The value " << i << " is not in any interval\n";
    }
}
```

Output:

```
The value -4 is not in any interval
The value -3 is not in any interval
The value -2 is not in any interval
The value -1 is not in any interval
The value 0 is in range (0,3)
The value 1 is in range (0,3)
The value 2 is in range (0,3)
The value 3 is in range (0,3)
The value 4 is in range (4,7)
The value 5 is in range (4,7)
The value 6 is in range (4,7)
The value 7 is in range (4,7)
The value 8 is in range (8,10)
The value 9 is in range (8,10)
The value 10 is in range (8,10)
The value 11 is not in any interval
The value 12 is not in any interval
The value 13 is not in any interval
The value 14 is not in any interval
The value 15 is not in any interval
The value 16 is not in any interval
The value 17 is not in any interval
The value 18 is not in any interval
The value 19 is not in any interval
```

The `testLookup` function returns a `std::pair`, where the `second` is set to `true` or `false` depending on whether the value is found in any range or not, and the `first` is the iterator to the range the value is found in.